# Why are compressed files modified at the end of compression?

Tags: archive, 7zip

Using 7zip I compressed ~15GB worth of pictures split in folders in 15 1024MB files.

Compression methode: LZMA2; Level: Ultra; Dictionary size: 64M;

At the end of compression some of the files had their "last modified" time changed to the time of completion, while some of the files didn't.

Why is this?

And if I have already uploaded most of the files will I be able to unarchive them successfully?

Answer (score 1):

You would need to ask the author of the program for an explanation of why it modifies volumes at the end of the operation. If I had to make an educated guess, it might be because 7-zip doesn't know which is the last volume until it's finished (because this would depend on the compression ratio of the files being archived, which can't be predicted), and so it needs to go back and update parts of the volume file headers accordingly.

In general, though, quoting the relevant 7-zip help file entry:

> **NOTE:** Please don't use volumes (and don't copy volumes) before
>   finishing archiving. 7-Zip can change any volume (including first
>   volume) at the end of archiving operation.

The only safe assumption is that you can't reliably use any of your individual 1GB volumes until 7-zip has finished processing the whole 15GB archive.